# Is there a difference in terms of sound quality between 1st, 2nd & 3rd pressing in Vinyl production?

Tags: vinyl-pressing

I am interested in [this](https://importantrecords.com/products/oliveros-dempster-panaiotis-deep-listening-band-2lp?variant=32630883778634) particular 1989 recording and there are various options available

- GOLD 2XLP
- BLACK 2XLP - $40
- CLEAR VINYL 2XLP (2ND PRESS) - $44
- FOGGY CLEAR VINYL (3RD PRESSING) - $44

What does the number of pressing imply in terms of quality, why are the following presses more expensive? <strike>And should I be concerned about differences in black/gold/clear/foggy or is it just aesthetics</strike>?

IIUC, following pressings can either be done with the same master (I assume the master wears off and the quality degrades?) or new master can be created from an original tape record, but I don't see such information on the listing.
What right questions should I ask the seller?

I asked the seller this, but I've received a vague evasive answer

> Hi,
> You should get a new copy directly from us. The first pressing was noisy and there's really no way to tell if you buy it used.

---

[Is there any difference in terms of sound quality between different vinyl colours?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/158/is-there-any-difference-in-terms-of-sound-quality-between-different-vinyl-colour)

Comment: My guess (just a guess!): a pressing is just a series of N vinyls pressed at the same time. It doesn't tell anything about the master: it may be the same as the previous pressing, or it may be a new one if the master used for the previous pressing was deemed low quality. My understanding of their answer is that the 1st pressing was flawed (so noisy you could think it is a second-hand vinyl) and thus you should buy a 2nd or subsequent pressing.

Comment: @xhienne Thanks! This is exactly what I had on mind, the 2nd and each additional pressing is such a broad term! Every source I find tells something different. Sometimes it means a batch, sometimes it means new master was made, sometimes it's both and sometimes its even a new batch with an old master.